# Sequelize: get reords created at a date

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In sequelize how to get all records created at a date. eg all records created at `2017-08-23`

There are a lot of similar questions here but all of them deal with getting records before or after a date which is not what i want.

I am using node 8.5.0 and sequelize 4.11.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up doing it this way

I used moment library

```
date = moment(date, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

then

```
Model.findAll({
    where: {
        createdAt: {
            $gt: date.toDate(),
            $lt: date.add(1, 'days').toDate()
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Just like this:

```
YourModel.findAll({
    where:{
        date: {$and:[{$gte:'2017-08-23 00:00:00'},{$lt:'2017-08-23 23:59:59'}]}
    }
});
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it gave me the idea to use range. Thanks.

Comment: @Caio Wilson i was going to reject your edit because you used newer language features there were not supported (or documented) in [Sequelize 4.11.0](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v4.11.0/docs/querying.md). Consider _adding_ newer syntax rather than replacing the original answer compeletly. I'll remove this comment in a couple of day when you'd a chance to read it. Don't reply with comments like "OK", "I understand" etc.